# Auto indentation in VIM, version 7.4.52, Operating Sysytem :Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, vim

I am new to this programming world, currently I am reading from "Introduction to Computation and programming using Python " by John V Guttag , MIT press.

How can I set the auto indentation on in VIM. What's happening now is that  when I press enter after : it starts from new line.

Is it possible ?

Comment: In command mode, have you tried `set smartindent` or `set autoindent`?

Comment: @birryree No. How to go to command mode.

Comment: It should be the normal mode you're already in when you first enter vim. Otherwise, you probably need to just press the `Esc` key and you should be in normal/command mode.  Then you type in `:` and type the commands I wrote. Also see the [vim documentation about source indentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code).

Comment: @birryree thank you very much .

Comment: Learning Vim and C at the same time is a very bad idea. Use normal editor.

Comment: @romainl Sorry but I did not get your point. I am learning python.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I typed "C". Don't learn `$LANGUAGE` and Vim at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim comes with several language indentation presets. To enable them, you need to add the following to Vim's user configuration file (`~/.vimrc`):

```
filetype indent plugin on
```

An easy way to do this from the terminal:

```
echo "filetype indent plugin on" >> ~/.vimrc
```

This appends the command to your `.vimrc`, creating it if necessary.

then open up a `.py` file and define a function.

Note: there are several other settings that can be very helpful to Python programmers and the [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code) from @birryree looks pretty complete.

I also use

```
set expandtab                     " Use spaces instead of tabs
set shiftwidth=4                  " Number of auto-indent spaces
set softtabstop=4                 " Number of spaces per Tab
```

in my `.vimrc` to follow PEP8.